# Is Redis v3.2.x backwards compatible with v2.8.x?

Tags: redis

I am attempting to upgrade from Redis 2.8 to 3.2. All functionality seems to remain intact in my application, but I am left wondering

- If there are a set of non-backwards compatible changes I need to take care of?
- If my data generated and persisted to disk in Redis 2.8 will work properly with the 3.2 server?

Comment: You should have not issues. I have an instances running that got upgraded from 2.8 to 3.0 and some to 3.2.

Comment: OK. I can't find any non-anecdotal evidence that the rdb file from 2.8 will still work with 3.2. Seems to be very little official documentation on this issue

Comment: I use it as a warm cache, not to persist data so I cannot speak to that aspect.

Comment: Ok, I need to retain data from before the upgrade.

Comment: You should be able to test that.

Comment: Yeah, I just ran the new instance with the old `redis.conf` file (which had the path to the old rdb file). Seems to work just fine. Only basic keys in the rdb file, still don't know for fact if there is anything that would break.

Answer (score 2):

Release notes are on github https://github.com/antirez/redis

Here's a snippet from the release notes for v3.0 and v.3.2

> Migrating from 2.8 to 3.0
>    =========================
>
> Redis 2.8 is mostly a strict subset of 3.0, you should not have any 
>     problem
>     upgrading your application from 2.8 to 3.0. However this is a list of 
>     small
>     non-backward compatible changes introduced in the 3.0 release:
>
> - The log format was modified. The prefix of each line included the pid
>     in the following format [1234]. Now instead it is 1234:? Where
>     '?' is actually the role of the instance. M for master, S for slave, C
>     if this process is a saving child (for RDB/AOF), and X for Sentinel.
> - The default maxmemory policy in Redis 3.0 is no longer "volatile-lru" as
>     it used to be in 2.8, but "noeviction". The policies behavior is the same
>     (but LRU eviction is much more precise in 3.0), so only the default value
>     changed. Just make sure to specify in your redis.conf what you mean.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/3.0/00-RELEASENOTES

> ## Migrating from 3.0 to 3.2
>
> Redis 3.0 is mostly a strict subset of 3.2, you should not have any problem
>   upgrading your application from 3.0 to 3.2. However this is a list of small
>   non-backward compatible changes introduced in the 3.2 release:
>
> - The default configuration file now binds to 127.0.0.1.
> - Slaves try to no longer expose stale data about already expired keys.
> - The RDB format changed. Redis 3.2 is still able to read 3.0 (and all the
>     past versions) files, but not the other way around.
> - Behavior on crash may be different. The crash log format changed and
>     the memory test executed is now different.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/3.2/00-RELEASENOTES